# How does one edit multiple tickets in Trac?

Tags: trac

I want to make changes to multiple tickets in Trac - specifically, change the value of several listboxes. A web search found multiple Trac tickets on the subject, with the master being (http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/525). Reading this ticket suggests to me that this feature has been implemented, but I can't find out how to actually do it. Our Trac "administrator" doesn;t know either. We are running Trac 1.01.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information can be found on the [TracBatchModify](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBatchModify) page. Navigate to the *Custom Query* page (`/query`) and you'll see a *Batch Modify* section at the bottom of the page provided you have `TICKET_BATCH_MODIFY` permission.

Comment: That was it, thanks. The term "Batch Modification" was what eluded me.